# How to index a dataframe for using ggplot in a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am struggling with creating multiple ggplots using a loop.
I use data in the following format:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(5,6,7,8)
c <- c(9,10,11,12)
d <- c(13,14,15,16)
time <- c(1,2,3,4)
data <- cbind(a,b,c,d,time)
```

What I want to create is a list of plots that plot one of the letters against the variable time.
Which I tried in the following way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plots <- list()
for (i in 1:4){
    plots[[i]] <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = data, aes(x = time, y = data[,i]))
}
grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], plots[[3]], plots[[4]])
```

This results in four times the fourth plot. How do I index this correctly in a way that creates the four intended plots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Up front: the reason that your plots are all identical is due to ggplot's "lazy" evaluation of code. See my #2 below, where I identify that the `data[,i]` is evaluated when you try to plot the data, at which point `i` is 4, the last pass in the `for` loop.)

1. It's generally preferred/recommended to use `data.frame`s instead of matrices or vectors (as you're doing here). It gives a bit more power and control.

   ```r
   data <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,time)
   ```
2. Also, I tend to prefer `lapply` to `for`-loops and `list`s, for various (some subjective) reasons. Ultimately, the issue you're having is that `ggplot2` is evaluating the data lazily, so `plots` is a list with four plots that make reference to `i` ... and that is realized when you try to plot them all, at which point `i` is 4 (from the last pass through the loop). One benefit of using `lapply` is that the `i` referenced is a local-only (inside of the anon-func) version of `i` that is preserved as you would expect.

   ```r
   plots <- lapply(names(data)[1:4],
     function(nm) ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = .data[[nm]])) + geom_line())
   gridExtra::grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]])
   ```

   [image: grid.arrange on two ggplots]
3. I also prefer `patchwork` to `gridExtra`, mostly because it makes more-customized layouts a bit more intuitive, plus adds functionality such as axis-alignment, shared legends, shared titles, etc. (None of those other features are demonstrated here.)

   ```r
   library(patchwork)
   plots[[1]] / plots[[2]] # same plot
   plots[[1]] + plots[[2]] # side-by-side instead of top/bottom
   (plots[[1]] + plots[[2]]) / (plots[[3]] + plots[[4]]) # grid
   ```
4. Ultimately, though, I suggest that facets can be useful and very powerful. For this, we need to melt/pivot the data into a "long format" so that the column names `a`-`b` are actually in one column.

   ```r
   reshape2::melt(data, id.vars = "time") |>
     ggplot(aes(time, value)) +
     geom_line() +
     facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y")
   ```

   [image: ggplot2 with facets]

   I assumed the preference for independent (free) y-scales, ergo the `scales="free_y"`. Try it without if you want to see the options. (There are also `scales="free_x"` and `scales="free"` (both).)

   To see what I mean by "long" format:

   ```r
   reshape2::melt(data, id.vars = "time")
   #    time variable value
   # 1     1        a     1
   # 2     2        a     2
   # 3     3        a     3
   # 4     4        a     4
   # 5     1        b     5
   # 6     2        b     6
   # 7     3        b     7
   # 8     4        b     8
   # 9     1        c     9
   # 10    2        c    10
   # 11    3        c    11
   # 12    4        c    12
   # 13    1        d    13
   # 14    2        d    14
   # 15    3        d    15
   # 16    4        d    16
   ```

   This can also be done with `tidyr::pivot_longer(data, -time)`, albeit the `variable` name is now `name`. For this use, there is no advantage to `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::pivot_longer`; there are opportunities for significantly more complex pivoting in the latter, not relevant with this data.

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b = c(5, 6, 7, 8), c = c(9, 10, 11, 12), d = c(13, 14, 15, 16), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```